# Different Outcome of Import from Excel to Access depending on Excel open or not

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I have a question regarding the form imported tables. 
I have an Excel Worksheet and I import different sheets from Excel to an Access DB. 
This is done via VBA, Trasnferspreadsheet.
I have realized that if the Excel wb is open the Dates will be saved as Number,
If the table is close however the correct format is considered.

Has anyone an idea why this is the case?

Comment: Please show your VBA code and mention the versions of Excel and Access. For me it works using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myTable", "P:\Mappe1.xlsx", True` with opened P:\Mappe1.xlsx as well as with closed. Used Excel 2007 and Access 2007.